# Get all CSS styles of an element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to select all CSS rules of an element with JavaScript?  I'm not looking for a specific solution, just as long as all CSS rules of a given element are read.

So, I have the following HTML

```
<div class='styledDiv' style='height:100px;width:100px;'></div>
```

and then in a separate CSS file:

```
.styledDiv
{
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: solid 5px blue;
}
```

I'd like the final result to include all inline and separate file CSS rules.  It doesn't matter in what format the final result is, be it a string or an array, whatever.

Let me also mention, I looked at some code that reads CSS rules from a separate CSS file.  I think there could be a better solution.  Also, FireFox and Chrome allow to loop through .style property the same way as looping through an array.  However, FF spits out -*tl-source rules for right and left border/margin/padding and doesn't show the actual CSS values.  Solution involving jQuery is also fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For FireFox, you can use this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:window.getComputedStyle

For IE, you can use this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535231(VS.85).aspx

**Be aware!**  You are treading on dark waters here.

These results return the browser's interpretation of CSS.  For example, when getting colors, IE would return the *HEX color codes* while Firefox returns *rbg code*.  And for font sizes IE would return the actual *inherited* font size while Firefox will return *pt* based.

Comment: Thanks.  Does .getComputedStyle() work in all other browsers, not only FF?  Outside the IE world?

Comment: So, I haven't had a chance to get deep into this, but I think this answer is pointing to the right path.  At least for now.  Thanks!