# Retrieve every CSS rule of an element

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to retrieve all of the CSS rules applied to an element, even if none has been applied (computed style by the browser), e.g.

```
alert($('#element').css());
```

Should have feature like this to show **every** css rule that can output like this:

```
position: static,
height: auto,
width: auto,
font-size: 100%,
line-height: 1,
z-index: 0
// and so on...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some info: [Get all CSS styles of an element with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576147/get-all-css-styles-of-an-element-with-javascript)

Unfortunately there's no solid solution, and it looks like there will be a few gotchas.
However, for simple debugging it should probably be good enough.

Comment: for simple debugging use firebug (or ie developer toolbar)

Comment: Hmmm. Plausible, jQuery should include this imo.